# Saving custom data types

Tags: iphone

Im making an app similar to apples weather app. My main view has a NSMutableArray of objects to be displayed. This array is managed by the user. I want to be able to save this array so that when the app is relaunched it has the stuff the user selected. The objects stored are "Event" objects which is a custom object type that stores more custom objects that all hold some of the following: NSString, NSNumber, NSUInteger, NSURL. My research has led me to three options, none of which i understand, nor know how to implement: saving to a plist using writeToFile, archiving the data, or saving it to userPrefs.
Does anybody know of a solution to my problem?

Sample data object: 
`

```
@interface Rider : NSObject {
    NSString *name;
}
-(Rider *) initWithName:(NSString *) nam;
- (NSString *)description ;


@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least two of those three options are reasonable. NSUserDefaults is really meant more for storing application preferences than as an option for storing the bulk of your data, so if you have a lot of data you should look at other possibilities first.

Property lists are easy to read and write, but you're limited to using a handful of standard types: NSString, NSData, NSArray, NSDate, and NSNumber. You can do quite a lot with those types, but since your own Event class is involved using property lists won't be so simple.

Archiving seems like the best plan. All you need to do is to adopt a simple protocol, NSCoding, in your custom classes (and make sure that the other classes that you use, like NSArray, also implement NSCoding). Then, create an instance of NSKeyedArchiver and ask it to archive your object graph. Recreating the object graph later is just as simple: create an NSUnarchiver instance with your file's data and unarchive your objects.

You can read about both archiving and property lists in the [Archives and Serializations Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047-SW1). Read that document before you go any farther.

There are other options as well -- you can always use the standard C file operations to write directly to a file if you want. It's unlikely that that will be as convenient as archiving, however.

Answer (score 0):

Your question itself has the answer.

Create each of your object as dictionary and finally you will have array of dictionaries.
NSArray and NSDictionary has the methods to write its data to a file (plist is preferred). If you use plist files, it will be easy to read again.